# React Hooks Change Text of Button on Click and then back again

Tags: html, reactjs, button, react-hooks, settimeout

Using React Hooks I would like to change the text of my button when a user clicks it to say "Added" and then I would like to set it back to the original text "Add to Cart" after 1 second. I assume I would use setTimeout for this but am having trouble figuring out how to use it in this case.

I have this

```
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Add To Cart");
```

and this so far.

```
  <button
    type="submit"
    onClick={() => setButtonText("Added")}
  >
    {buttonText}
  </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `timeout` inside `useEffect`, and pass buttonText as dependency, every time the buttonText is updated, the timeout will restore the default text value:

```
const text = "Add To Cart" 
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState(text);

 useEffect(()=> {
    const timer = setTimeout(()=> {
       setButtonText(text);
    }, 1000);
    return ()=> clearTimeout(timer);
 }, [buttonText])
 
 return (<button
    type="submit"
    onClick={() => setButtonText("Added")}
  >
    {buttonText}
  </button>)
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-upsr5i)

Comment: Thank You! Yes This works great.

Another question I is if am using useState elsewhere in the same component. Will this override the previous call of useState?

Comment: Do you mean call setButtonText(text) in other part of the component?

Comment: I am brand new to this React Hook business. haha. But I couldn't figure out how to use my current click handler to also change the word of the button so I thought I would use 2 (never tried it before) 

the first 1 adds things to the cart and uses useState

the second would be this one. 

but adding this one breaks the first.

Comment: <button
        className="add"
        type="submit"
        disabled={!available || adding}
        onClick={handleAddToCart}
        onClick={() => setButtonText("Added")}
      >

Comment: Yes, the second onClick will override the first one, but you can create a function to call both (handleAddToCart and setButtonText), ie: const handleClick = () => {handleAddToCart(); setButtonText("Added") }, then inside button: onClick={handleClick}

Comment: Haha have you ever gotten so far along in a topic you have forgot the basics...no just me then? Wow thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this way should work:

```
<button
   type="submit"
   onClick={() => {
   setButtonText("Added");
   setTimeout(() => {
     setButtonText("Add To Cart");
      }, 1000);
     }}
   >
    {buttonText}
 </button>
```

Here an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-change-text-of-button-on-click-and-then-back-again-qhbzv?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Let's use useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    setButtonText("Add To Cart")
  }, 1000)

  return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutID )
}, [buttonText])
```

Comment: The callback will trigger after each change of state. This way we will take care of clearing the timeout after the operation.

Comment: @nullptr as the state keep the same value, it will not detect changes and this block will not be executed again.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `onClick` handler to this

```js
onClick={
setButtonText("Added");
setTimeout(() => setButtonText("Add to Cart"), 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I made https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-kilby-nicm4?file=/src/App.js

I just used setTimeout to make it a 1 sec change after i got the update button title from the function.